# how to use system globe key and delete key in custom keyboard?

Tags: ios, custom-keyboard

I'm trying to make a custom keyboard.
I saw the guide in apple developer said, "Your custom keyboard must also provide a way to switch to another keyboard".
So, I think that it's a good idea to use system globe key.
But, I cant find the methord or property to show them.
Please help me, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe those are available to you. You would have to make your own buttons and then make IBActions that correlate to whichever option you are trying to do for the corresponding button:

Globe (next keyboard) - [self advanceToNextInputMode];

Delete - [self.textDocumentProxy deleteBackward];